# How to disable startup developer game logos when loading the game?

Tags: civilization-6

I can disable the game intro movie in the options but how can I disable the logos from showing when the game starts. I dislike how loud they are and im sure my fast computer can load the game faster without them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/58xfjx/psa_civ_vi_logo_skip/

You cannot remove the logo movie or the game will hang while loading. You can substitute the file with a very short movie file. Wiperight is basically a short graphic movie file. Here is a actual blank file I am using. http://www.geocities.ws/xbdvdrg/blank.zip

Navigate to you game folder

```
steamapps\Common\Sid Meier's Civilization VI\Base\Platforms\Windows\Movies
```

Backup `logos.bk2 as logos.BAK` (note, the reddit contains a link to an actual blank movie file)

Copy `WipeRight.bik as logos.bk2` (Note the extension change)

### Bonus

The same reddit mentions "The same minihack can be used to speed up diplomacy.". "There are still some fade-out delays at times, such as when a leader gives you his introduction after the first meeting but it will save some delays."

*I have performed this change too but not noticed any immediate time saving.*

After performing the same backup and replace of the file `LeaderScreen_WashIn_Mask.bik`, the transition delay when talking to leaders is sped up.